# Turning list of atoms into a single list using recursion

Tags: list, recursion, lisp, scheme

I'm looking for an answer that turns a list of atoms into a single list recursively.

An example would be, `(slist '(a (b c) (d e (f) g) h))` into `(slist (a b c d e f g h))`

Any answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called *flattening* a list. Here are a bunch of options:

```
; required predicate

(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (null? x))
       (not (pair? x))))

; naïve version using append

(define (flatten1 lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         '())
        ((not (pair? lst))
         (list lst))
        (else
         (append (flatten1 (car lst))
                 (flatten1 (cdr lst))))))

; naïve version using append, map, apply

(define (flatten2 lst)
  (if (atom? lst)
      (list lst)
      (apply append (map flatten2 lst))))

; efficient version using fold-left

(define (flatten3 lst)
  (define (loop lst acc)
    (if (atom? lst)
        (cons lst acc)
        (foldl loop acc lst)))
  (reverse (loop lst '())))

; very efficient version with no higher-order procedures

(define (flatten4 lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst)
             (acc '()))
    (cond ((null? lst)
           acc)
          ((not (pair? lst))
           (cons lst acc))
          (else
           (loop (car lst) (loop (cdr lst) acc))))))
```

Any of the above will work as expected. For instance, using `flatten4`:

```
(flatten4 '(a (b c) (d e (f) g) h))
=> '(a b c d e f g h)
```

Depending on the interpreter you're using, it's quite possible that it already includes an implementation. For example, in Racket:

```
(flatten '(a (b c) (d e (f) g) h))
=> '(a b c d e f g h)
```

Comment: so that's called flattening.
thanks a lot. that's a lot of learning. :D

Answer (score 1):

In Lisp, as opposed to Scheme, you have to accept the fact that the atom `nil` represents an empty list in your list structure. So, strictly speaking, when you flatten a list, you do not obtain **all** of the atoms from the tree structure; only those ones that do not represent empty lists and list terminators.

You also have to make a design decision: does your code handle improper lists and circular list? That is to say, what should these cases do:

```
(flatten '(a . b))  ;; (a b), accurate diagnostic or failure?

(flatten '#1=(a . #1#))  ;; (a), accurate diagnostic or failure?
```

Do you handle the situation and collect the actual non-list atoms that are present in the tree structure, regardless of cycles or improper termination? Or do you detect the situation accurately and report a meaningful diagnostic? Or just ignore the possibility and let the code blow up in lower level functions, or perform runaway recursion?

If you don't care about dealing with improper lists and circular structure, flattening a list is recursively defined like this.

1. A non-list is flattened by returning a list containing that atom.
2. A list is flattened by flattening all of its elements and catenating them.

In Lisp it's usually easier and clearer to write the code than the English spec or pseudo-code:

```
(defun flatten (obj)
"Simple flatten: no handling of improper lists or cycles"
   (if (listp obj)
     (mapcan #'flatten obj)
     (list obj)))
```

Note that although `mapcan` is destructive, that doesn't present a problem here, because it only ever catenates list structure that is constructed within our function call and not any incoming list structure. Stated in other words, our output does not share structure with the input.

Comment: thanks for answering. btw can lend a little help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125198/sorting-in-scheme-following-a-pattern

Answer (score 0):

You've already checked a correct answer, but here is a trivial implementation which clearly indicates the recursion:

```
(define (slist list)
  (if (null? list)
      '()
      (let ((next (car list))
            (rest (cdr list)))
        (if (list? next) 
            (append (slist next) (slist rest))
            (cons next (slist rest))))))
```

Comment: thanks, that can also be. btw, can you help me on this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125198/sorting-in-scheme-following-a-pattern