# Sorting in scheme following a pattern

Tags: sorting, scheme, dutch-national-flag-problem

A little help, guys.
How do you sort a list according to a certain pattern
An example would be sorting a list of R,W,B where R comes first then W then B.
Something like `(sortf '(W R W B R W B B))` to `(R R W W W B B B)`

Any answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a special procedure that only sorts lists of R, W, and B?

Comment: OP is trying to implement a functional version of the dutch national flag problem. It's a bit pointless, the really interesting solution works on arrays (or vectors), a linked-list implementation won't be as efficient ... or elegant

Answer (score 3):

This is a functional version of the [Dutch national flag problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem). Here are my two cents - using the `sort` procedure with `O(n log n)` complexity:

```
(define sortf
  (let ((map '#hash((R . 0) (W . 1) (B . 2))))
    (lambda (lst)
      (sort lst
            (lambda (x y) (<= (hash-ref map x) (hash-ref map y)))))))
```

Using `filter` with `O(4n)` complexity:

```
(define (sortf lst)
  (append (filter (lambda (x) (eq? x 'R)) lst)
          (filter (lambda (x) (eq? x 'W)) lst)
          (filter (lambda (x) (eq? x 'B)) lst)))
```

Using `partition` with `O(3n)` complexity::

```
(define (sortf lst)
  (let-values (((reds others)
                (partition (lambda (x) (eq? x 'R)) lst)))
    (let-values (((whites blues)
                  (partition (lambda (x) (eq? x 'W)) others)))
      (append reds whites blues))))
```

The above solutions are written in a functional programming style, creating a new list with the answer. An optimal `O(n)`, single-pass imperative solution can be constructed if we represent the input as a vector, which allows referencing elements by index. In fact, this is how the original formulation of the problem was intended to be solved:

```
(define (swap! vec i j)
  (let ((tmp (vector-ref vec i)))
    (vector-set! vec i (vector-ref vec j))
    (vector-set! vec j tmp)))

(define (sortf vec)
  (let loop ([i 0]
             [p 0]
             [k (sub1 (vector-length vec))])
    (cond [(> i k) vec]
          [(eq? (vector-ref vec i) 'R)
           (swap! vec i p)
           (loop (add1 i) (add1 p) k)]
          [(eq? (vector-ref vec i) 'B)
           (swap! vec i k)
           (loop i p (sub1 k))]
          [else (loop (add1 i) p k)])))
```

Be aware that the previous solution mutates the input vector in-place. It's quite elegant, and works as expected:

```
(sortf (vector 'W 'R 'W 'B 'R 'W 'B 'B 'R))
=> '#(R R R W W W B B B)
```

Comment: Where is the interesting vector version? :)

Comment: thanks! glad to have learned several ways of implementing this. lol didnt know that this is called dutch national flag prob.

Comment: @leppie there you go, a vector version :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution without using `sort` or higher order functions. (I.e. no fun at all)
This doesn't really sort but it solves your problem without using sort. `named let` and `case` are the most exotic forms in this solution.

I wouldn't have done it like this unless it's required not to use sort. I think [lepple's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18125356/1565698) is both elegant and easy to understand.

This solution is `O(n)` so it's probably faster than the others with very large number of balls.

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base))

(define (sort-flag lst)
  ;; count iterates over lst and counts Rs, Ws, and Bs
  (let count ((lst lst) (rs 0) (ws 0) (bs 0))
    (if (null? lst)
        ;; When counting is done build makes a list of
        ;; Rs, Ws, and Bs using the frequency of the elements
        ;; The building is done in reverse making the loop a tail call
        (let build ((symbols '(B W R))
                    (cnts (list bs ws rs))
                    (tail '()))
          (if (null? symbols)
              tail ;; result is done
              (let ((element (car symbols)))
                (let build-element ((cnt (car cnts))
                                    (tail tail))
                  (if (= cnt 0)
                      (build (cdr symbols)
                             (cdr cnts)
                             tail)
                      (build-element (- cnt 1) 
                                     (cons element tail)))))))
        (case (car lst)
          ((R) (count (cdr lst) (+ 1 rs) ws bs)) 
          ((W) (count (cdr lst) rs (+ 1 ws) bs)) 
          ((B) (count (cdr lst) rs ws (+ 1 bs)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a lookup eg

```
(define sort-lookup '((R . 1)(W . 2)(B . 3)))

(define (sort-proc a b)
  (< (cdr (assq a sort-lookup))
     (cdr (assq b sort-lookup))))

(list-sort sort-proc '(W R W B R W B B))
```

Runnable R6RS (IronScheme) solution here: http://eval.ironscheme.net/?id=110

Comment: i see your sorting. but can you give me an implementation of using car, cdr and a bunch of conditions and put it in a single definition. i seem to not fully understand.

Comment: most scheme implementations have some sort of built-in sort. They take two arguments, the data structure to be sorted and the predicate your want to sort by.

Answer (score 1):

You just use the built-in sort or the sort you already have and use a custom predicate.

```
(define (follow-order lst)
 (lambda (x y)
  (let loop ((inner lst))
  (cond ((null? inner) #f) 
        ((equal? x (car inner)) #t)
        ((equal? y (car inner)) #f)
        (else (loop (cdr inner)))))))
```

(sort '(W R W B R W B) (follow-order '(R W B)))

;Value 50: (r r w w w b b)

Comment: thanks a lot. but could it be simplier? I mean only the function name(follow-order lst) is used to execute the function, combining sorting to the order? Something like: (follow '(W R W B R W B))

Comment: Sure, but to me that seems almost too specific. (define (follow lst) (sort lst (follow-order '(r w b))))

Comment: aah. well still thanks, i really understood your implementation.